# syslog-ng freezes when reloading config changes in log msg size

Tags: syslog-ng

I'm having a weird case of syslog-ng freezing on some reloads and under some conditions.

syslog-ng version is ubuntu 20.04's default `3.25.1`. It has to be something related to `log_msg_size` as this started to happen when it was reconfigured from `log_msg_size(16384)` to `log_msg_size(65536)` which, in fact, is its default value.

Once it was reconfigured the daemon was left in state `Reloading configuration` according to `systemd`, and stopped login at all. Also, it was not responding to `TERM` signal having to forcefully kill it. In this state any attempt to reload config got an error warning about an already existing config reloading.

If this was not oddly enough, killing the daemon, starting it with `log_msg_size(16384)` and then stopping it normally and reconfiguring it again to `log_msg_size(65536)` makes the reload work correctly until something happens and the reload start to hang the process in the described state.

Any clues of what I could be missing? I've tried to remove the option completely and let it get its own defaults, but it seems that still happens the same.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a bug. Please open a GitHub issue: https://www.syslog-ng.com/community/b/blog/posts/contacting-the-syslog-ng-team-reporting-problems-asking-questions

Comment: I do not have enough time to investigate the issue and maybe the bug was already solved, but not in ubuntu's default package as it sounds quite similar, but not the same to https://github.com/syslog-ng/syslog-ng/pull/3075 

Afaik that patch never reached ubntu's default 3.25.1.